# How to change an attribute in a foreach instruction (xslt)

Tags: xml, xslt

I use Indesign and import an xml file with xslt
My xml file is like this :

```
...
<_04_Questions>
    <_04_QuestionsTitre>Ceci est le titre 1</_04_QuestionsTitre>
    <_04_QuestionsTexte>Ceci est le texte 2</_04_QuestionsTexte>
    <_04_BlocAncreA1 href="file:/images/myimage1.png"></_04_BlocAncreA1>
</_04_Questions>
<_04_Questions>
    <_04_QuestionsTitre>Ceci est le titre 1</_04_QuestionsTitre>
    <_04_QuestionsTexte>Ceci est le texte 2</_04_QuestionsTexte>
    <_04_BlocAncreA1 href="file:images/myimage2.png"></_04_BlocAncreA1>
</_04_Questions>
...
```

I want to add after each <_04_Questions> a new image called for example "imagesupp01" for the first instance, "imagesupp02" for the second…

A part of my xslt is like that :

```
<xsl:for-each select="Randoland/_04_BlocTexte/_04_Questions">
...
<xsl:element name="_04_BlocAncreA1">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="_04_BlocAncreA1/@href"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
...
????
</xsl:for-each>
```

What can I add ???? to add new image, all different after each step ?
Thank you

Comment: Please post the expected result. Without it it's not clear what you mean by "add a new image called ... ".

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need `xsl:for-each` at all, you can just do

```
<xsl:template match="_04_BlocAncreA1">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <element>
    <xsl:text>imagesupp</xsl:text>
    <xsl:number count="_04_questions" format="001"/>
  </element>
</xsl:template>
```

Not sure what you want the element called, I just used `element` here, but it should demonstrate the concept.

This assumes you want the new element immediately after the `_04_BlocAncreA1` element. It's the same thing in your code sample, but if what you actually need is for the new element to go at the end of the `_04_Questions` element, then you can use this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="_04_Questions">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <element>
      <xsl:text>imagesupp</xsl:text>
      <xsl:number count="_04_Questions" format="001"/>
    </element>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hello Flynn, I want to insert a new element after each _04_BlocAncre1, but this new element must have a new value after each _04_BlocAncre1. For example the value of the first element is "001", for the second "002", the third "003"…

Comment: This is too verbose even for XSLT. Consider: `<element><xsl:text>imagesupp</xsl:text><xsl:number count="_04_Questions" format="001"/></element>`.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I forgot about the format attribute on `xsl:number`, I don't often use it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you Michael and Flynn,

Comment: It's really what I wanted ! That's fine ! and Happy new year !